# iText PDF Concatination fails - InvalidPDFException

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to concatenate 2 PDFs using itext 4.2.0 utility. For few cases, it throws InvalidPDFException in below code

```
reader = new PdfReader("c:\tmp\test.pdf");
```

> com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: No message found for
>   trailer.not.found     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.rebuildXref(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(Unknown Source)

This PDF is valid one- I opened it in Text editor and ensured it has %PDF as well as %EOF as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12363773/7258025)

**UPDATE**

The iText version is 2.1.7. The jar was wrongly named as 4.2.0.

The path mentioned ("c:\tmp\test.pdf") is sample one. We are sending as "c:/tmp/test.pdf"

Comment: Replace `"c:\tmp\test.pdf"` by `"c:\\tmp\\test.pdf"` - or do you really have file names with horizontal tab characters in them?

Comment: iText 4.2.0 was never released by iText Software. I strongly recommend that you either use 2.1.7 or 5.5.10.

Comment: Please share the PDF file in question for analysis. Without that we can only assume that it is defect.

Comment: iText up to version 2.1.7 is `com.lowagie.*`. Anything above 2.1.7, incuding the infamous gork by ymasory/InProTopia, is `com.itextpdf.*`. If your exception is `com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException`, then your iText version is most definitely *not* 2.1.7.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse AFAIK 4.2s also use `com.lowagie.*` (the 4.2.0 tag had been applied just before the package change), so the OP seems to actually use a 5.x AGPL version.

Comment: In any case, the OP needs to edit the question and provide clarity.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no iText 4.2.0. Please throw it away. It is a rogue version that is not released by the official developers of iText. It's a "gork", meaning God Only Really Knows what's inside. **Solution: Throw away iText 4.2.0 and replace it with a more recent, official version:** https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases
2. You get the error saying that the actual error message for the key `trailer.not.found` is not found. This means that you are using an iText jar that isn't build correctly. The `.lng` files are missing from the jar, hence the actual error message can't be found. **Solution: Throw away iText 4.2.0 and replace it with a more recent, official version:** https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases
3. The key `trailer.not.found` corresponds with the message "Trailer not found". It means that you are trying to create a `PdfReader` with a file that may look like a PDF, but that isn't. For instance: it starts with `%PDF-`, but there is no trailer. That means that iText searches the file (that should end in `%%EOF`; please check if this is the case) and the keyword `startxref` can be found. In other words: the trailer is missing. **Solution: check if the PDF is valid.** Note that old versions of iText weren't able to read PDFs that use a feature that was introduced after version PDF 1.5. Maybe your "unofficial" iText version is that old...
4. Finally: `\` is an escape character. This is wrong: `"c:\tmp\test.pdf"` because if reads as "c:**[tab]** mp **[tab]** est.pdf" where **[tab]** is the tab character `\t`. You should use either `"c:/tmp/test.pdf"` or `"c:\\tmp\\test.pdf"`.

Comment: Thanks. iText version is 2.1.7, not 4.2.0 as i mentioned in the update.  All my PDFs are in database already. I just downloaded this PDF and trying to insert new PDF ( This new PDF page is created by iText) into existing one. I am able to open the downloaded PDF in reader and if i open in it text editor, i am able to see %PDF, %%EOF,startxref as you recommended.  but when i am trying to create PdfStamper with this downloaded pdf, then i am facing the exception. The same code works for some pdfs( same use case)

Comment: You know that 2.1.7 should be used in commercial environments, do you? See [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) There are some unresolved legal issues in 2.1.7 that were only fixed in iText 5. Moreover, iText 2.1.7 dates from 2009. Many things have improved since that date.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: shouldn't that be: _should *not* be used in commercial environments_?